# how to verify that Gratuitous ARP disabled in a Linux server?

Tags: linux, security, arp, hardening, spoofing

**Problem:**

I need to verify if Gratuitous ARP is disabled on a Linux server in the configuration files.

Comment: Would http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Using_arptables_to_disable_ARP help you ? It would inapacitate all your box comm (ipv4,ipv6) though. So maybe, disabling ARP at iface level is what you want... To supress ARP on interface eth0 run the following command as root: `ip link set dev eth0 arp off` ...

Comment: Gratuitous ARP on the other hand is generally not something that happens spontaneously, it occurs if and when the network admin needs it , via cli. So not sure what you mean by **disabling** `garp`. It's not like it happens at the server's whim...

Comment: Tell us more, so we can understand your question.

Comment: If you're wondering why you are asked to tell more, here's some context: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @A.B: the Angela scene in example 2 is actually hilarious. +1 ;-D

Comment: I want to disable a gratuitous arp because they facilitate arp related attacks, such as arp poisoning attacks.